# Why the tyres of vehicles are always found to be black?

Tags: material-science

Generally, it happens. I never seen vehicles with tyres of different color other than black..?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the color of tires and not physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tires are black as most manufacturers add carbon black to rubber to dramatically reduce wear and tear. You can buy colored tires though if you wish.

Comment: [Are Colored Tires Finally Going To Happen?](http://jalopnik.com/are-colored-tires-finally-going-to-happen-1755438524)

Comment: @Keepthesemind: Looks like colored tires are produced (http://www.doublestartyre.cn/Doublestar/vip_doc/843752.html - the text seems to be machine-translated though) , but it is difficult to find out how to buy them.